# Newbie help: mouseover on image sometimes returning wrong image from image map

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, web, mouseover

Have www.website.com/sds/ (index.htm) set up so that a mouseover on various places shows an image.
For some reason image 2.jpg and 3.jpg (move mouse back and forth on blue balloon) are both showing up (not at same time) when you mouse over the blue balloon. Only 3.jpg (child in chair) should show up on the blue balloon.

2.jpg (found on pink balloon) works fine on pink balloon.
I changed the map from "poly" to "rect" with new coords for images 2 and 3 thinking that may help but it did not.
2.jpg comes up fine on pink balloon.

Any help appreciated,
PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-made the areas for your balloons, you had quite a mess of coords right there.
Just replace the `n.jpg` with the file name for that balloon's number on the reference image.

Update:
Changed the polygons to circles since they're showing some inconsistencies.
Hope this time it works. And we can close this question too.

[alt text http://thismayhem.com/img/stackoverflow.png](http://thismayhem.com/img/stackoverflow.png)

And those are the codes for each of them:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="231,49,46" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('1.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/> 

<area shape="circle" coords="273,112,31" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('2.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/> 

<area shape="circle" coords="169,150,33" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('3.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/> 

<area shape="circle" coords="97,159,32" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('4.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/> 

<area shape="circle" coords="134,59,38" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('5.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/>

<area shape="circle" coords="67,87,28" href="" onmouseover="changeImage('6.jpg')" onmouseout="resetImage()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Someone else did some of the coordinates for me. I changed them as you instructed. I think it really may be a caching issue since I now see it on the pink balloon. It should show always show 3.jpg but sometimes it will show 7.jpg and even 1.jpg. 
Oh well, using ie 7. Latest firefox likes to flash pictures without even moving optical mouse once mouseover is enacted and you leave mouse idle.
Thanks so much
Peter

Comment: JohhnyArt-any other ideas on above?
Thanks
Peter

Comment: My only guess would be that the polygons have gone mad inside the image, I'm going to try with circles at the centre of the balloons to see if it solves anything. Check back in a while

Comment: Thanks, tried it. Still does it a bit with images 7 and 3 but thats fine - an anomaly. I appreciate all of your fine work.
Peter